# get-pip.py broken on Windows 10

Tags: python, pip

Get Pip (Python file from [Pypa.io](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)) on Windows 10 is not extracting on my laptop. I followed all the instructions on [pypa.io - Installing](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/), however, when I tried to execute the file, despite many attempts to fix this, it says:

```
ERROR: To modify pip, please run the following command: C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip
```

So I ran `C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip` and then it shows another error message:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named pip
```

I then consulted with a friend of mine, and he said that the second error message is obviously not a file error, but (me reflecting now) is quite logical. Of course it says that there is no module named pip because that was the very thing that I am trying to download. Then it occurred to me that Python must think that I already have it because it is asking me to *modify* pip. So I looked into this and saw that I had a pip folder but nothing inside it to do with Python.

So this made me think *Why is it not downloading?*
or *Why does it think that I already have it?*

***UPDATE***

The Python installer now comes with an option to install pip which should solve any further problems!

[image: Python Installer]

Comment: `pip` is usually packaged with Python. So unless you have an old version of Python, you probably have `pip` too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty sure that I had the exact same problem as you. I am using Python 2.7.14 64-bit, and when I try to install pip using get-pip.py, I get the exact same error.

I fixed this by simply running the following command:

`python -m ensurepip --default-pip`

This then installed pip. This is because the version of Python I downloaded is packaged with pip.

Note that this installed pip without the wheel portion, so I then had to run:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

After that, everything was ready to go.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i do not have the *'ensureip'* module

Comment: @NR ensurepip not ensureip, it's a built in library https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/ensurepip

Comment: Python 2.7 - No module named ensurepip

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled upon this very same issue. However, I am using (have to) Python 2.7.8 32-bit.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/ clearly states that

> pip is already installed if you are using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 downloaded from python.org

so that my call to `python -m ensurepip --default-pip` did in fact result in `No module named ensurepip` (as I am *not* using `>=2.7.9`).

Yet I was finally able to get pip running: instead of using the latest `get-pip.py` at https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py I used https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/get-pip.py.

For future reference, and those who want to compare against any version of `get-pip.py` in https://github.com/pypa/get-pip:

```
29af88001263a19911c0911057cc192e  ./get-pip.py      did *not* work for me,
e4bd67ad4de5329bd4291e06ee3ba012  ./2.6/get-pip.py  *did* work for me.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to install Python and Pip from the executable from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

pip.pypa.io seems to make installing Python harder than it has to be. Maybe it has a special use case.

Edit:
I also recommend uninstalling the current version you have now so there are no conflicts.